# Setting horizontal menu and footer links to the right

Tags: css, html, html-lists, footer

I can't set my menu to be aligned all the way to the right of the page, and my footer links also. Here's what I have http://prntscr.com/32snbr and this is what I want http://prntscr.com/32snrm

This is my html, please help

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Lab exercise 4">
    <meta name="keywords" content="FINKI, Lab Exercise, Web design">
    <style>
    body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #4f8295;
    }

    li
    {   
    float:left;     
    }
    ul.foot{
    display:inline; 
    list-style-type:none;
    }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0;   margin-bottom: 0; max-width: 62.5rem; background: #fff; padding: 15px;"> 
        <div style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
            <img src="ukim-logo-9.png"/>
            <img src="finki-logo-9-en.png"/>
        </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%; text-align: left; float:right; padding-top:15px;"> 
                <ul class="foot">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
                        <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.1.html">Home</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
                    <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.2.html">News</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
                    <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.3.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
                    <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <hr style="border: solid #dddddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 1.25rem 0 1.1875rem; height: 0;">

    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 65%; padding-left: 20px;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; width:100%">
                <h1 style="font-size: 40px; margin-bottom:0;">Get in touch</h1>
                <h3  style="margin-top:0;">Contact content</h3>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width:100%; ">
                <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet 
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper 
                    suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p>
                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu 
                    feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan 
                    et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 
                    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue. 
                </p>                        
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;vertical-align: top">
            <div style="display: inline-block; ">
                <p>Map</p>
                    <img style=" display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%" src="gmaps.JPG">
                <p>Awesome St. <br>1000 Skopje, MK</p>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <hr style="border: solid #dddddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 1.25rem 0 1.1875rem; height: 0;">

        <div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;">
                    <footer>
                        <span>&copy; Faculty for Computer Science and Engineering - Skopje</span>                       
                    </footer>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 49%; text-align: right; "> 
                    <ul class="foot">
                        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.1.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.2.html">News</a></li>
                        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.3.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your style section

```
.footerright{
align: right; 
}
```

Then add replace what you have in the footer with this.

```
<div class="footerright">
    <ul class="foot">
        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.1.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.2.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.3.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a style="padding: 15px" href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ditch the UL and LI and use a P tag and align it to the right

Comment: No problem, aligning footers can often be a pain.

Comment: Could you help me with aligning the the menu items too? I tried the same method but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you want the menu items aligned left, right or center?

Comment: Right (same as the footer), but I don't want the logos to be on the right too, just the menu links.

Comment: ah, I see. I'll fix it up for you now

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; max-width: 62.5rem; background: #fff; padding: 15px;"> 
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
        <img src="ukim-logo-9.png"/>
        <img src="finki-logo-9-en.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: top; width: 50%; text-align: right; float:right; padding-top:15px;"> 
    <ul>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
            <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.1.html">Home</a></li>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
        <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.2.html">News</a></li>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
        <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lab4/lab4.3.html">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top:15px;">  
        <li><a style="background-color: #008cba; text-decoration: none; border-color: #007295; color: white; padding: 15px;" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works with a minor adjustment (there's one closing div tag that is not needed in this part), but it looks like it moves the entire content to the right and it looks like some kind of overlap http://prntscr.com/334gdw

Comment: The div is closed off, so there shouldn't be anything else moving apart from the 4 buttons

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: You can always enclose the whole navigation bar in another div.

Comment: I just saw my mistake, I missed one part of my previous code when erasing before replacing it with yours and that was messing it up. Thank you, it works perfectly now.